# Как двигать элемент UI Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Мне нужно что-то похожее на `transform.position += new Vector3(0, 10, 2)` чтобы сделать анимацию для исчезания `UI` элемента. Как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У UI свой transform с своей 2д координатой.

```
RectTransform rect = transform as RectTransform;
rect.anchoredPosition += new Vector2(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

UI элементы вместо Transform используют RectTransform ( https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html ) что, собственно, видно даже в инспекторе если кликнуть на юайный элемент.

Соответственно:

```
RectTransform rt = toggle.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
```

а дальше делаешь необходимые действия

Но все анимации меню я советую делать не вручную а при помощи библиотеки LeanTween - там есть инструментарий предназначенный напрямую для этого.